# ERROR: No matching distribution found and ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, pip, package, virtualenv

I'm trying to install the requirements of a GitHub clone in a virtual environment created by `py -m virtualenv objectremoval` command, but I always encounter the "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" Error. After cloning the repo, I performed the following lines;

```
D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>py -m virtualenv objectremoval
created virtual environment CPython3.10.2.final.0-64 in 1474ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.1.2, setuptools==62.6.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>cd objectremoval\Scripts

D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval\Scripts>activate

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval\Scripts>cd ..

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval>cd ..

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>pip install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python==3.3.0.10 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv_python==3.3.0.10

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>pip install opencv_python==3.3.0.10
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python==3.3.0.10 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv_python==3.3.0.10

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>pip3 install opencv_python==3.3.0.10
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python==3.3.0.10 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv_python==3.3.0.10

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>py -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python==3.3.0.10 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv_python==3.3.0.10

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>pip install tensorflow==1.10.1
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.10.1 (from versions: 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.10.1

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>pip install numpy==1.13.3
```

The Error was too long for numpy, you can find it with this hyperlink:
https://justpaste.it/7vxkv

Also, checking the local packages shows me all installed packages in the global environment. I think this is a relevant problem too.

```
(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>pip list --local
Package                      Version
---------------------------- -------------------
absl-py                      1.0.0
argon2-cffi                  21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings         21.2.0
asttokens                    2.0.5
astunparse                   1.6.3
attrs                        21.4.0
backcall                     0.2.0
beautifulsoup4               4.11.1
black                        22.1.0
bleach                       5.0.0
cachetools                   5.0.0
certifi                      2021.10.8
cffi                         1.15.0
.
.
.
.
```

Also `where python` and `where pip` commands does not show the virtual environment paths if I execute them in the main virtual environment folder.

```
(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>where python
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal>where pip
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
```

However, it adds an extra path if I execute the `where python` and `where pip` commands in Scripts folder:

```
(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval\Scripts>where pip
D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe

(objectremoval) D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval\Scripts>where python
D:\test1\Deep-Object-Removal\objectremoval\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Neither trying to install the packages in the main folder nor in the Scripts folder gave me desired results.

My requirements.txt file includes only the following packages:

```
opencv_python==3.3.0.10
tensorflow==1.10.1
numpy==1.13.3
```

Also, I have tried to upgrade pip, setuptools, and wheel versions. I have also tried to create a virtual environment with conda by `conda create -n <venvname>` command, and tried several different python versions, but these were also not helpful. Can you please help me to solve the problem? Thank you for your valuable time.

```
Python: 3.10.2
OS: Windows10 x64 Pro
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chosen package called [Deep-Object-Removal](https://github.com/VPanjeta/Deep-Object-Removal) seems to be very outdated (last commit 4years ago) and not maintained any longer, i would suggest to search for any currently supported alternative.

If you try to install this version of `opencv_python` in a clean python venv (with `python3.10`) you get an error:

```py
pip install opencv_python==3.3.0.10
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python==3.3.0.10 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv_python==3.3.0.10
```

If you have a look at the files at [pypi for this version of `opencv_python`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.3.0.10/#files) you notice that this version of the pkg. has been [yanked](https://pypi.org/help/#yanked).
Additional there is no pkg. for `python3.10`, the last support whl file seems to be for `python3.6`.
You can try to adapt the `requirements.txt` with a newer one of `opencv_python` or install `python3.6` and download the specific version by hand and install the `whl` file,( but this may lead to new errors).
But again i would recommend to use another, currently supported package instead of Deep-Object-Removal.